# Enable WordPress Sessions

Tags: session

I'm wondering why WordPress does not support sessions and many people out there claim that putting the following code in functions.php might not be a good idea (it in fact works for me but returns PHP warnings, too):

```
function cp_admin_init() {
if (!session_id())
session_start();
}

add_action(‘init’, ‘cp_admin_init’);
```

Is it good idea to enable sessions in WordPress? What would be the correct way to do this?

Comment: The warning come from your wrong quotes: `‘` is no valid quote. Use `"` or `'` instead.

Comment: @kaiser It changed when I did copy/paste. It it correct quote.

Comment: What do you want WP to do with session? Session is a part of PHP and you can use it whenever you want, WP just don't use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The reason for not working `$_SESSIONS` in WP Core:

The thing WordPress is doing with sessions is burdened inside [`~/wp-includes/load.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.4.2/wp-includes/load.php#L10).

The responsible function for resetting the `$_SESSION` to `null` is `wp_unregister_GLOBALS()`. So in case you really need it, you'll have to turn `register_globals` off in your `php.ini` file.

```
/**
 * Turn register globals off.
 *
 * @access private
 * @since 2.1.0
 * @return null Will return null if register_globals PHP directive was disabled
 */
function wp_unregister_GLOBALS() {
    if ( !ini_get( 'register_globals' ) )
        return;

    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['GLOBALS'] ) )
        die( 'GLOBALS overwrite attempt detected' );

    // Variables that shouldn't be unset
    $no_unset = array( 'GLOBALS', '_GET', '_POST', '_COOKIE', '_REQUEST', '_SERVER', '_ENV', '_FILES', 'table_prefix' );

    $input = array_merge( $_GET, $_POST, $_COOKIE, $_SERVER, $_ENV, $_FILES, isset( $_SESSION ) && is_array( $_SESSION ) ? $_SESSION : array() );
    foreach ( $input as $k => $v )
        if ( !in_array( $k, $no_unset ) && isset( $GLOBALS[$k] ) ) {
            $GLOBALS[$k] = null;
            unset( $GLOBALS[$k] );
        }
}
```

### The idea behind it?

> Also of note, is that technically there is no real need for sessions, there are always other avenues. Sessions rely on a session ID to validate and provide continuance, but these can be intercepted/predicted/stolen, at which point someone can impersonate you

<sup>*- by @TomJNowell in the comments.*</sup>

Comment: Also of note, is that technically there is no real need for sessions, there are always other avenues. Sessions rely on a session ID to validate and provide continuance, but these can be intercepted/predicted/stolen, at which point someone can impersonate you

Comment: @TomJNowell This should be more an edit of my answer :)

Comment: Indeed but I'd rather not interfere =p

Comment: yeah "no need for sessions" I loled, sorry. But you can live without television too. "Television can influence you with bad things, so we disable it". LOL. It's very useful. But I'm _not_ surprised that the WP people are actually defending disabling sessions because they think there is no need for them... bravo

Comment: let me ask you something, let´s say user (not logged int) comes to your website from an advert, and you want to make some components on the website behave differently. You can do it for the page where the user lands to, but how you will do it after he navigates to another page, or closes the site and revisits it, without using session and or cookies to remember that that user came from an advertisment

Comment: @ErikKubica use query parts (URl).

Comment: @kaiser it works only if you are passing required query params to all links user clicks. Still does not solve if user closes the window/tab and revisits the web after XY minutes (session) or a day/month/year (if using cookies), there will be no more url attributes, so the custom website behaviour based is lost. So passing query params is not a solution in that case.

Comment: @ErikKubica In case you used Cookies and the user is switching devices or clears that in between, than it's lost as well. If you need something sticky or permanent, use ETags (not really, unless you're an AdServer). Sessions are meant to run out and get deleted after X minutes of inactivity.

Comment: @kaiser in my case usually I do only simple things like, if user came from a facebook advert or google advert then user will see different phone number on the contact us page, but users don´t land directly to the contact us page, or they close the browser and revisit in one day. For that purpose cookies are the best. So cookies would be the best option instead of session since as you said session lasts only few minutes. But WP completely destroys cookies too, but workaround using javascript would do the trick, but in few cases I need to set some session/cookie from php.

Comment: @ErikKubica try local storage instead of Cookies. It's the same, runs nowadays everywhere and is less limited than Cookies.

Comment: @kaiser yes, but local storage is not accessible from php. In case things are just client side, it ś fine to use local storage. Basically sometimes there is need for session/cookies that both server and browser can read.

Comment: @ErikKubica then use a key value storage like Memcached (not so good), Redis (better) or Hazelcast (best option). Those are easy and cheep to install, all can serve their duty as cache servers as well and the first two got good integrations. In case you are proficient with PHP and got a very good knowledge around web tech in general, you might hide meta data in 1pixel images (old tracking tech), SVG (might get blocked by ad blockers or you might get reported) or use an ETag (don't, if you do not know what you are doing). Hope that helps.

Comment: @ErikKubica All in all, your comments should go into a separate question. This is extended discussion here and you should take your time to phrase a good question, work in the comments, show how far you got and – in the best case – answer the question yourself to share your knowledge, as I did for you here (in the wrong place).

Comment: @kaiser I get you I know all these technologies used them multiple times. Most of the times you work with client that has 2€ per month shared hosting and you need cheap and fast solution without any redis and other bad-ass caching solutions. There are lot´s of frameworks, content management system that are secure and still use and relies on cookies & session for example magento, symfony. Wordpress´s excuse for not using cookies/sessions is just lame, they should implement a feature like defining in wp config to true/false (other than php conf) to let developer decide if they need it or not.

Comment: @ErikKubica I had your clients as well. First thing I always did was to convince them that they should buy into GitHub, a cheap CD solution and invest into a setup that involves WP Starter and a 20-50€/m hosting. In most times I was successful, which made a much better experience for _their_ clients. Faster time to first byte means more sales, impressions, whatever. Anyway, you could at least try to move them to DigitalOcean or Vultr or similar to get more bang for the bucks. You can use Memcached as well (http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.set.php). Or just exchange WP for something better.

Comment: @kaiser i agree but the VPS discussion if offtopic right now. Memcache/transient are key/value, you need a uniqe key for the user to remember him for few days that he came from an advert and you want to have him customized experience. IP/Browser agent is not reliable for key, it can change anytime like session. This is why cookies exist, wp disabling cookies is like a overprotecting parent, sure there are lot of devs that store sensitive information in cookies sessions, but this is not reason to force all devs to not use them.